# Retrieved JSON list/array, cannot access all of the attributes on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, web-services

I have created a webservice which places my data into a list and have converted it to JSON. The following is my JSON output.

```
{
    GetEventLTResult: [
        {
            eventID: 1,
            location: "Place A",
            type: "Community"
        },
        {
            eventID: 2,
            location: "Place B",
            type: "Community"
        },
        {
            eventID: 3,
            location: "Place C",
            type: "Movie"
        },
        {
            eventID: 4,
            location: "Place D",
            type: "Community"
        }
    ]
}
```

On the angular side, I have called the webservice. I manage to retrieve and display the whole JSON.

```
$http.get('http://localhost:24007/WebService.svc/GetEventLocationType')
         .success(function (JsonObject) {
             // Success callback

             $scope.message = JsonObject; //manage to output
             $scope.message1 = angular.fromJson(JsonObject); //manage to output
             $scope.message2 = angular.fromJson(JsonObject.eventID); //unable to output
             $scope.EventLTlist = [
                            angular.fromJson(JsonObject.GetEventLTResult[0].eventID), //manage to output, tried with other arrays
                            angular.fromJson(JsonObject.GetEventLTResult[0].location) //unable to output, tried with other arrays
             ];

         })
         .error(function () {
             // Failure callback
             $scope.errMsg = "Please try again.";

         });
```

My goal is to retrieve all the location and type and populate the DDL each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `fromJson` within the callback because JsonObject is not a json string it is an object already that was converted internally by `$http`

You could do something like:

```
$scope.EventLTlist = JsonObject.GetEventLTResult;
```

Then in the view you can use `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="evt in EventLTlist">
   {{evt.location}}
</div>
```